# Multiple VPN devices with the same IP

Tags: linux, vpn, ip, iproute2

Well, this is a rather awkward inquiry and I'm pretty pessimistic about it, but lets see what the community has to say.

The scenario: 
A server connecting to multiple VPN endpoints doing all sort of stuff.

The problem:
The same IP can be assigned to multiple devices.

The challenge:
Be able to route traffic successfully through each of these devices with the same IP address.

In the following scenario:

```
    tun0: 192.168.200.10  192.168.200.1
    tun1: 192.168.200.11  192.168.200.1
    tun2: 192.168.200.12  192.168.200.1
```

No problems. Using Linux's sources based routing things work like a charm.
However, since I don't control from the client side the IP address I'm going to be assigned, I might get:

```
    tun0: 192.168.200.10  192.168.200.1
    tun1: 192.168.200.10  192.168.200.1
    tun2: 192.168.200.10  192.168.200.1
```

And here comes the problem. Is there a way to control routing tables per interface regardless of IP?

Currently each interface that goes up gets another entry in */etc/iproute2/rt_tables* such as:

```
    100 tun0
    101 tun1
    102 tun2
```

Then the following for each device:

```
    ip rule add from 192.168.200.X iif tunX table tunX
    ip route add default via 192.168.200.1 table tunX
```

In order to test it I'm using 'curl --interface tunX'.
The first interface more or less "wins" the routing decision.
I want the right interface to win.
Theoretically I'm well aware I'm doing something many would consider wrong. However I'd like to know if there is a way around it, because I think there is.
Any ideas about it? Perhaps iptables fwmark could help if at all?

Comment: You had to expect this, so... in what possible way is his better than avoiding IP conflicts/what's the use-case here?

Comment: As said, multiple VPN client connections on one server. I get assigned the same IP address, that's all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use the same IP address on two different interfaces without *something* breaking, and there are no good "workarounds". One or more of the networks will have to renumber.

(Oh, and now it's time to get yourself some IPv6, which doesn't have this problem.)